# Reading number of characters and words in a file

Tags: c++, file, io, fstream

I tried to write a program to find out the number of characters and words in a file:

```
/*
Write C++ program to count:
Number of characters in a file
Number of words in a file
Number of lines in a file
*/
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int countOfCharacters = 0;
    int countOfWords = 0;
    ifstream ins;
    ins.open("hello.txt", ios::in);
    char c;
    while (ins.get(c))
    {
        countOfCharacters += 1;
    }
    cout << "Total Number of characters is " << countOfCharacters << endl;
    ins.seekg(0,ios::beg);
    while(ins.get(c))
    {   cout << "Character is " << c <<endl;
        if (c==' ' || c=='.' || c=='\n'){
        countOfWords+=1;
        }
    }
    cout << "Total number of words in the file is " <<countOfWords <<endl;
    ins.close();
return 0;
}
```

For the following input:

```
Hi Hello Girik Garg
```

I get the output as:

```
Total Number of characters is 19
Total number of words in the file is 0
```

Can someone tell why I am not getting the right number of Words?

Comment: Does "hello.txt" actually contain `Hi Hello Girik Garg`?

Comment: Yes.. @user306038-----

Comment: Reading in one character at a time is going to be really slow. At least read a line at a time and spin through your string using a pointer on `c_str()` or via an index. You can also do your character counts and your word-break counts at the same time. There's no need for two passes here.

Comment: Does your debugging code show anything useful?

Comment: For the quantity of characters in a file, you can use the size of the file.  Seek to the end, then read the file position.  A better method is to use an Operating System function to read the file size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you reach the end of the file in the first read routine `eofbit` flag is set to `true`, in order to be able to read from the same stream without closing/reopening it, you need to reset it:

```
//...
ins.clear(); //<--
ins.seekg(0, ios::beg);
//...
```

That being said, you could do both counts in the same cycle, as suggested by @YSC:

```
while (ins.get(c))
{        
    countOfCharacters += 1;
    if (c == ' ' || c == '.' || c == '\n')
    {
        countOfWords += 1;
    } 
}
```

Note that if the line doesn't end with a `\n`(or `'.'`/`' '`) the last word is not counted, and you should verify if the stream is indeed open:

```
if(ins.is_open(){ /*...*/}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what are error flags, and why I need to clear them?

Comment: By the way, the way you suggested is working fine.

Comment: @loveofprogramming, when you reach the end of the file the first time `eofbit` flag is set, you need to reset it.

Comment: @loveofprogramming note that if you don't have a newline at the end of the line it will only count 3 words

Comment: @loveofprogramming here is a nice link with a simple explanation about error flags and how they work https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/

Comment: Or maybe... count words and characters in a unique pass?

Comment: @YSC ahahah, I don't know, I'm just here to find bugs ;)